# How to prove non-regularity with Myhill-Nerode theorem?

Tags: regular-languages

I have a problem in proving of nonregularity of EQ_n = {u = v2v : |v| = n}. I just dont know how to start. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If the alphabet is only $\{2\}$, then the language is regular.

Otherwise, there's at least one other letter, let's say $a$. Then the infinitely many words $a^i2$ are all pairwise non-equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that it's preferable in that case (and in general too) to use the conclusion of myhill-nerode theorem which is: if there are infinite strings such that every two strings $w,s$ satisfies $w\not\equiv_Ls$ then the language $L$ isn't regular.

So in your case, you can take the strings $w_i=a^i2$ and the string $z=a^i$. For each $i,j\in\mathbb{N}$ and $i\neq j$:
$$w_i\circ z=a^i2\circ a^i\in L$$
$$w_j\circ z=a^j2\circ a^i\notin L$$

The first string is $a^i2a^i$ then it's in the language since $|a^i|=|a^i|$. However, the second string is $a^j2a^i$ and since $i\neq j$ then $|a^i|\neq|a^j|$ and therefore the string isn't in the language.

We have found infinite strings such that for every two strings $w,s$, $w\not\equiv_Ls$ and therefore $L$ isn't regular. QED.